# React this.props.history.push()

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using the history object of `this.props.history.push("/url")`. I am being navigated to the URL passed in the push function, But when I hit back in the browser, only URL changes to the previous state but it is not being loaded. Any solution to this or any alternative method to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can we see some code please  ?I'd be easier to help

Comment: Can you please post a code sample?

Comment: are you sure that the previous url is correct??

Comment: Below is the api call and after that rendering the page based on id. When I click back, I should be able to redirect and load the previous form page. This code is in form page.  https://pastiebin.com/5ec3e86071360